# What is wrong with my camera overlay iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera-overlay

Whenever I run my app on a device and I choose to take a picture it crashes without warning can someone tell me what is wrong with my overlay?

CameraOverlay.h does not contain anything besides making UIView the superclass.

CameraOverlay.m

```
@implementation CameraOverlay

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.opaque = NO;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        // load an image to show in the overlay
        UIImage *constraints = [UIImage imageNamed:@"camera_overlay"];
        UIImageView *constraintView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:constraints];
        constraintView.frame = CGRectMake(30, 100, 260, 200);
        [self addSubview:constraintView];

    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

viewController.m

```
- (IBAction)scanButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    CameraOverlay *overlay = [[CameraOverlay alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was wrong, I was setting the overlay of the camera before I set the source to the camera.

Updated code from the `ViewController`

```
- (IBAction)scanButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    CameraOverlay *overlay = [[CameraOverlay alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;


    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```